# Django AWS RDS Postgres TTFB too slow

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a Django app that uses two databases. One database is hosted on AWS, that I use to manage the users (users email and password). Then there is a second db that is using sqlite3 that is stored in the users laptop (local database). The app is ran locally (not hosted on a server). The only query that is done for the database hosted on AWS, is when the user logins. After that, all the queries are down on the local database. The local database has no relation to the database hosted on AWS.

I don't know why but when I use the database hosted on AWS I get a high TTFB. Does anyone know how I can reduce this time? Oddly enough if I use a local data instead of the one running on AWS I get way faster TTFB.

Thanks!

[image: TTFB Results]

Comment: Is this on every call regardless of query, on every *login* call, or only on the *first* login call? What region are you in and what region is the DB in? How much data is being hosted? What is the RDS instance's CPU, memory and disk storage? Are you near full capacity? What does the login call do? Are you using the official SDK? If so, boto2 or boto3? We need a lot lot lot more information to be able to help :)

Comment: Thanks for the help! This happens for every page. I noticed that if the user is not logged in, the pages loads really fast because the TTFB reduces a lot. I'm using AWS S3 and RDS, the free version. The memory and disk storage are practically empty. I'm not hosting any data on the server side. I only have the amazon DB so that I can login the users. After the user is login all the queries, DB lookup is done in the users local database. Hope it makes sense!

Comment: So once you are logged in, the TFFB is extended? Or only when logging in?

Comment: What region is the DB in and what region are you in?

Comment: Thanks again! To answer you question. The TFFB is extended only when I'm logged in. 
The AWS S3 and RDS is in Europe (Frankfurt), and I'm in the US. I checked with a friend that is in Europe, and his TTFB is half of what I have, but it's still around 0.5s.

Comment: So the DB works normally when not "logged in"? How are you logging in? The issue may not be the database

Comment: Yes, it works normally when I'm not logged in. I login by using the authentic feature from Django. So I don't think the issue could be there